# Why is ADB hanging on me?

Tags: android

Adb as working fine for me right up until today.  Now, when I try to run adb kill-server,  adb just hangs.  If I set ADB_TRACE to 1, I get
`C:\Users\Jamie\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools>adb devices
system/core/adb/adb.c::main():Handling commandline()
system/core/adb/adb_client.c::adb_query():adb_query: host:devices
system/core/adb/adb_client.c::_adb_connect():_adb_connect: host:version`

Then it just sits there.  I'm out of ideas!

Comment: Have you looked [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17116121/adb-hangs-when-trying-to-start-or-stop-server) ?

Answer (score 1):

It turned out that it was happening because of something completely unrelated.  Recently,  I disabled my firewall from autostarting due to boot time issues.  When I started it up manually, it popped up a warning dialog about ADB.  When I answered yes to that, it started working.