# ADB doesn't start

Tags: android, windows, adb

I downloaded Android SDK with Android Studio but ADB commands do not work at all.

I added `%ANDROID_HOME%\platform-tools` to PATH but it doesn't help.

When I type `adb start-server` adb.exe appears in task manager for a second then crashes.

[image]

I tried this `>set ADB_TRACE=1` and reinstalling but it didn't help.


*Install log with error -1073741819*

[image]

it's driving me crazy
Can someone help?

Comment: Have you checked out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15663010/adb-is-not-starting-no-error-message  Look at the solution that currently has 3 upvotes.  It has some steps to possibly solve this.

Comment: Yes, I tryied this. Not work(.

Comment: How about this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5703550/my-eclipse-adb-server-didnt-ack-failed-to-start-daemon  Further down there is an answer which shows you how to list (via command line) what apps are listening on ports.  It can be that adb is trying to load on the same port that another program is already running on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can Update your SDK with latest version.

Please try to uninstall & again re-install it.

Hope this will solve your problem !!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

type:

echo export "PATH=~/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools:$PATH" >> ~/.bash_profile

then close the terminal and reopen it